# После запуска на томкате вылезает ошибка, HTTP Status 500 - com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, tomcat

```
package com.testproject.util;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
            "Gmail API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/2/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/gmail-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS, SheetsScopes.DRIVE);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
                Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = null;
        try {
            credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                    flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Gmail client service.
     * @return an authorized Gmail client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Gmail getGmailService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Gmail service = getGmailService();

        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        String user = "me";
        ListLabelsResponse listResponse =
                service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
        if (labels.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No labels found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Labels:");
            for (Label label : labels) {
                System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}

----------
package com.testproject.rest;

import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.testproject.util.GoogleAPI;
import com.testproject.util.Quickstart;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.IOException;

@Path("/gmail")
public class MailSenderGoogleAPI {
    private static String to = "wsevolodmail@gmail.com";
    private static String from = "wsevolodtest@gmail.com";
    private static String subject = "Hello!";
    private static String text = "bla bla bla";

    @GET
    @Path("/send")
    public static Response sendEmail() throws MessagingException, IOException{
        Gmail gmail = new Quickstart().getGmailService();
        MimeMessage message = GoogleAPI.createEmail(to, from, subject, text);
        GoogleAPI.sendMessage(gmail, "me", message);
        return Response.status(200).entity("OK").build();
    }
}


----------

    package com.testproject.util;

import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class GoogleAPI {

    public static void sendMessage(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage email)
            throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email);
        message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

        System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
        System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
    }

    private static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email)
            throws MessagingException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        email.writeTo(baos);
        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
        return message;
    }

    public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject,
                                          String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
        InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
        InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress(from);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(bodyText);
        return email;
    }

}
----------
```

Comment: private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS, GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM,
                    GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY, GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY, GmailScopes.GMAIL_METADATA);

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте в него полный текст ошибки.